On the induced morphism between colimits in an $\infty$-category
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category (quasicategory), $F\colon K\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ and $y$ a colimit of $F$. To be precise, there is a colimit cone $\overline{F}\colon K\ast\Delta^0\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ that restricts to $F$ on $K$ and to $y$ on the cone point. Then, there is a zig-zag of Joyal equivalences $\mathcal{C}_{F/}\leftarrow\mathcal{C}_{\overline{F}/}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{y/}$ between (ordinary) slices induced by these restrictions. If we now let $i\colon L\rightarrow K$ be a map of simplicial sets, we obtain an induced diagram $Fi\colon L\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, suppose similarly there is a colimit cone $\overline{Fi}\colon L\ast\Delta^0\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ with colimit $x$. This induces a morphism $g\colon x\rightarrow y$, unique up to contractible choice, inducing a square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}_{F/} @>>> \mathcal{C}_{Fi/}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathcal{C}_{y/} @>>> \mathcal{C}_{x/}
\end{CD},$$
which commutes up to homotopy (the bottom map is induced as pre-composition with $g$, itself only determined up to contractible choice).
Now, in Markus Land's Introduction to Infinity-Categories, Observation $4.3.23$, he claims that we can in fact choose a model for $g^{\ast}$ that makes this square strictly commute. He states this can be done by inverting the left vertical Joyal equivalence, but this is not at all clear to me! To get a commutative diagram like that, it would have to admit a retraction and not just an inverse equivalence, but this seems unlikely. If we replace the vertical maps by the zig-zags used to define them, it is easy to lift $\mathcal{C}_{F/}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{Fi/}$ to a functor $\mathcal{C}_{\overline{F}/}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{\overline{Fi}/}$ using this method, but then I don't see how to "push this down" to a functor $\mathcal{C}_{y/}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_{x/}$. This "observation" is used in the important Theorem on the decomposition of colimits, so I would like to understand it properly. Any help is appreciated.
